# How to color GuideLine in Plottable.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, plottable

I'm trying to find a simple way to color a `GuideLineLayer` from Plottable.js.

I tried the following so far.

1) trying to use `attr()` inside `onAnchor()`
This adds the attr to the `g` element containing the `line` element, but doesn't seem to have any effect. Could it be CSS precedence?

```
 var guidelineMax = new Plottable.Components.GuideLineLayer('horizontal')
    .value(222)
    .onAnchor(function(c) {
      c.content().attr('stroke', '#F00')
    })
    .scale(yScale)
```

2) using `addClass()`
This is completely unintuitive, as it colors the boundary of the chart, instead of the guideline.
[image: screenshot 2016-03-31 18 07 43]

```
.red {
  stroke: #F00;
}

 var guidelineMax = new Plottable.Components.GuideLineLayer('horizontal')
    .value(state[state.param].max)
    .addClass('red')
    .scale(yScale)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was close with my second solution. `addClass()` adds the given class to the `component-group`, which meant I had to modify my CSS to target only the guideline.

```
.plottable .guide-line-layer.red .content line.guide-line {
  stroke: #FF0000;
}
```